# How to get url parameter in activated link in angular 7 and call rest api from service class

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular7

I want to fetch data using id field using Get parameters.
Follwing is my html url code which is redirecting to specific page but doesn't call the service to fetch rest api

```
  <a [routerLink]="['/usedCars/detail', lists.id]" class="btn btn-danger">Read more...</a>
```

Below is my service.ts function and i have implemented **import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';**

```
getcarDetail(id:string){
    return this.http.get<Autocardetail>(this.ServerUrl + 'autocardetail/'+id).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

Below is my component.ts file where i am calling the service on ngOninit function.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap} from '@angular/router';
import { Autocardetail } from '../autocardetail';
import { AutopostService } from '../autopost.service';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-autopostdetail',
  templateUrl: './autopostdetail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./autopostdetail.component.css']
})
export class AutopostdetailComponent implements OnInit {
  detail$: Observable<Autocardetail>;
  constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private autopostService: AutopostService
      ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.detail$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
        return this.autopostService.getcarDetail(params.get('id'))
    })
    );
  }
}
```

Below is my class file

```
export class Autocardetail {
  id: string;
  car_name: string;
  car_model: string;
  car_built: string;
  car_manufac_year: string;
}
```

Below is a postman example how a response look like,

```
{
    "car_id": "0",
    "car_name": "Nissan",
    "car_model": "Sunny",
    "car_built": "Nissan inc",
    "car_manufac_year": "2019",
    "usedcarimages": [
        "0_Nissan-1.jpg",
        "0_Nissan-2.jpg"
    ]
}
```

I am using this website as reference https://www.truecodex.com/course/angular-project-training/service-and-http-client-for-blog-detail-recent-blog-and-categories-angular

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: No i am not getting any error but it also doesn't call the api request from service class

Comment: check my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only potential problem I think in your code is in the usage of `swtichMap()`.

**Currently-**

```
switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
  this.autopostService.getcarDetail(params.get('id'))
)
```

The code instruction `this.autopostService.getcarDetail(params.get('id'))` **should be in the same line** as that of `swtichMap()` if you are using **arrow function** or explicit `return` statement needs to be mentioned if you are breaking the line.

**Correct ways-**

```
switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
  return this.autopostService.getcarDetail(params.get('id'))
})
```

or

```
switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.autopostService.getcarDetail(params.get('id')))
```

Comment: @nilay You need to specify `return` just before `this.autopostService....`. Check the 2 ways properly.

Comment: Yes added return but still not calling service method.

Comment: @nilay Can you update your question above, with the code you have changed in your editor.

Comment: @nilay Can you make a stackBlitz here https://stackblitz.com/